# No wifi after kernel upgrade to 4.10

Tags: wireless, kernel, firmware

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 on an ideapad, with a  7260 intel card. Wifi works fine on 4.6, but after going to 4.10 I started getting a "no suitable firmware found" error message and no wifi. I rolled back to 4.6, but, is there any way of making it work with 4.10?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of: `dmesg | grep iwl` run from kernel 4.10 when the wireless is not working.